# Iterators over same collection in for-loop

Tags: scala, iterator

Assume i want to generate all combinations of subsets of a Set. Since `subset` returns an `iterator` I don't want to convert it to something strict.

```
def gen(A: Set[Int]) = {
  val it0 = A.subsets
  val it1 = A.subsets
  for(a <- it0; b <- it1) yield (a,b)
}
```

but it does not what I want. For Example `gen(Set(1,2,3)).foreach(println)` returns:

```
(Set(),Set())
(Set(),Set(1))
(Set(),Set(2))
(Set(),Set(3))
(Set(),Set(1, 2))
(Set(),Set(1, 3))
(Set(),Set(2, 3))
(Set(),Set(1, 2, 3))
```

It seems only the second iterator iterates over all subsets. Why does it behave like that and is there a nice way to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `it0` and `it1` are `Iterator`s. You can't use iterators like this:

```
val it0 = Iterator(1, 2)
val it1 = Iterator(1, 2)

(for { a <- it0; b <- it1 } yield (a, b)).toList
// List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2))
```

The reason here is that you can't re-iterate over `Iterator`, `Iterator` is mutable. For the first element of `it0` you have iterated over `it1`, so `it1` is empty for next elements of `it0`.

You should either re-create second iterator for every element of first iterator:

```
def gen(A: Set[Int]) = 
  for{
    a <- A.subsets
    b <- A.subsets
  } yield (a,b)
```

Or convet `Iterator` to immutable collection:

```
def gen(A: Set[Int]) = {
  val it = A.subsets.toSeq
  for(a <- it; b <- it) yield (a,b)
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, thx. Flaw in my thinking. I wanted to avoid converting it to an immutable collection.

Comment: But now that I tested it, my algorithm (which also does some other stuff) is like 3x slower than my initial solution with the immutable collection.. Too bad. Just wanted to save some space.

Comment: @Kigyo: The [implementation of subsets](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/SetLike.scala#L175) is expensive and includes `N` calls of expensive `toIndexedSeq` operation (1 for `len` from `0` to `Set#size`).