# Scala Streams: how to avoid to keeping a reference to the head (and other elements)

Tags: scala, recursion, stream

Suppose I have a tail recursive method that loops over the elements of a `Stream`, like this (simplified code, not tested):

```
@tailrec
def loop(s: Stream[X], acc: Y): Y = 
  s.headOption match {
    case None => acc
    case Some(x) => loop(s.tail, accumulate(x, acc))
  }
```

Am I keeping references to the head (and all other elements) of the stream while iterating, which I know should be avoided?
If so, then what is a better way to achieve the same thing?

The code that calls this is (I hope) not keeping a reference.  Suppose `list` is a `List[X]` then the code is calling

```
loop(list.sliding(n).toStream, initialY)
```

EDIT:
I know this can be done easily without tail recursion (e.g. using `foldLeft`) but the non-simplified code is not looping exactly one element at a time (sometimes `s` is used instead of `s.tail` and sometimes `s.tail.dropWhile(...)` is used.  So I'm looking to find out how to correctly use `Stream`.

Comment: What does `accumulate` doing here? From the code, I think `loop` is probably a wrong name here. Looks like `Y` is a collection here and if so then what you have done is perfectly alright.

Comment: @Jatin what `accumulate` does and what `Y` is (fictional type) is not important here, just wanted to show that something is being done with the current element and the accumulated result.  I think `loop` is fine since I'm looping over all the elements of the stream.

Comment: @herman: thank you! It's the best question I have ever answered!

Comment: I'm curious -- why did you make the function take a Stream as opposed to an Iterator?  `list.sliding(n)` is already an Iterator, so the code would be simpler.  It would probably be somewhat more efficient to use an Iterator as well.  Also, Iterator is a more general interface, and (from what I can see here) all you need.  And by avoiding Streams you would eliminate the memory concerns you speak of.  If you really wanted to call it with a Stream, no problem -- Streams can give you Iterators.

Comment: @AmigoNico: `Iterator` is mutable - it could lead to [strange errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20738649/406435).

Comment: It's true that you can't reuse an Iterator, but your question is expressly about how you can ensure that you do *not* hold on to the old entries in your Stream, so you aren't going to be able to iterate over the Stream twice either.  Your `loop` method clearly just goes through the Stream sequentially, a single time; that's exactly what Iterator is for.  But if you use a Stream, you need to ensure that the *caller* knows not to hold on to the Stream head.  In your example, if the caller does `val x = list.sliding(n).toStream; loop(x, initialY)` then you are screwed.

Comment: Said another way, you've chosen a collection type designed to remember previously computed values and are asking "How can I make sure I don't hold onto previously computed values?  I just want to iterate through them."

Comment: In fact, you could accept a Traversable -- even more general than Iterator -- and your loop method could just do a simple fold: `( initialY /: list.sliding(n) )( (soFar,x) => accumulate(x,soFar) )`.  At that point you may not even need to define a method at all -- just do the fold inline.  Ah!  That was Kevin's answer -- spot on.

Comment: @AmigoNico the simplified code goes one at a time but as mentioned in the edit already, the actual method does not (sometimes calls itself with the s instead of the s.tail, sometimes with s.tail.dropWhile(...) to skip over some elements).  It never goes back so I guess an iterator would work.  I think the main reason is that, being a Scala newbie, I wanted to follow advice and try to not use mutable objects (such as `Iterator`) unless profiling would indicate that my code is slow due to immutability.

Comment: @AmigoNico Regarding your comment "you've chosen a collection type designed to remember previously computed values" --> this memoization is only part of the `Stream` function.  Isn't it first of all a lazy list implementation?  Is there some other immutable (to the outside at least) type that stays lazy (i.e. does not perform memoization)?  Even the [Stream documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream) shows how to avoid memoization by not hanging on to the head.

Comment: Just to be clear, if that Stream-based method is not private then it's a land mine -- it will either do the right thing or crash the app depending on whether the caller keeps the Stream head (for a long Stream).  If it's private so that only you can call it, then fine -- you can just be careful.

Comment: "Isn't it first of all a lazy list?"  To get a lazily computed data stream, one of three things has to be true: 1) you memoize the data you have already calculated, 2) you recompute it each time it is requested, or 3) you don't allow access to the previously computed data.  (1) is Stream; (2) would only be immutable if the function is pure (which Scala doesn't know) and would only perform acceptably if the function is quick, and (3) is Iterator.  An immutable, non-memoizing collection that calls a potentially impure function to lazily generate values is presumably impossible.

Comment: @AmigoNico Well, in my case (not the simplified code in the question) I am sometimes requesting the same element multiple times, thus not advancing to the next element (so memoization is useful there) but don't need the previous elements anymore, so naturally I don't want to hang on to the memoized elements that I don't need anymore.  And yes, the `@tailrec loop` function exists inside another function thus is `private` and `final`.

Comment: In that case it sounds like Stream is a reasonable choice, and I apologize for the noise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr:** your method `loop` is correct, there will be no reference to the head of the stream. You could test it on infinite `Stream`.

Let's simplify your code sample to the limit:

```
class Test {
  private[this] var next: Test = _

  final def fold(): Int = {
    next = new Test
    next.fold()
  }
}
```

Note that your `loop` method is also a method of some object.

The method is `final` (just like `Stream#foldLeft`) - it's very important.

With `scalac -Xprint:all test.scala` after tail recursion optimization you'll get this:

```
final def fold(): Int = {
  <synthetic> val _$this: Test = Test.this;
  _fold(_$this: Test){
    ({
      Test.this.next = new Test();
      _fold(Test.this.next)
    }: Int)
  }
};
```

And this code will not help you to understand what is going on.

The only road to the magical land of understanding is the `java` bytecode.

But you should remember one thing: there is no such thing as `method of object`. All methods are "static". And `this` is just the first parameter of the method. If the method is virtual there is such thing as [vtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_table), but our method is final, so there will be no dynamic dispatch in this case.

Also note that there is no such thing as parameter: all parameters are just variables, initialized before method execution.

So `this` is just the first variable (index 0) of the method.

Let's take a look at the bytecode (`javap -c Test.class`):

```
public final int fold();
  Code:
     0: aload_0       
     1: new           #2                  // class Test
     4: dup           
     5: invokespecial #16                 // Method "<init>":()V
     8: putfield      #18                 // Field next:LTest;
    11: aload_0       
    12: getfield      #18                 // Field next:LTest;
    15: astore_0      
    16: goto          0
```

Let's write this method in pseudo scala-like code:

```
static foo(var this: Test): Int {
  :start // label for goto jump

  // place variable `this` onto the stack:
  //   0: aload_0       

  // create new `Test`
  //   1: new           #2                  // class Test
  // invoke `Test` constructor
  //   4: dup           
  //   5: invokespecial #16                 // Method "<init>":()V

  // assign `this.next` field value
  //   8: putfield      #18                 // Field next:LTest;

  this.next = new Test

  // place `this.next` onto the stack
  //  11: aload_0       
  //  12: getfield      #18                 // Field next:LTest;

  // assign `this.next` to variable `this`!
  //  15: astore_0      
  this = this.next // we have no reference to the previous `this`!

  //  16: goto          0
  goto :start
}
```

After `this = this.next` we have no reference to the previous `this` on stack or in the first variable. And the previous `this` can be removed by `GC`!

So `tail.foldLeft(...)` in `Stream#foldLeft` will be replaced with `this = this.tail, ...; goto :start`. And since `this` is just a firs argument of method `@tailrec` before `foldLeft` declaration makes sense.

And now we can finally understand `scalac -Xprint:all test.scala` result:

```
final def method(a: A, b: B, ...): Res = {
  <synthetic> val _$this: ThisType = ThisType.this;
  _method(_$this: Test, a: A, b: B, ...){
    ({
      // body
      _method(nextThis, nextA, nextB, ...)
    }: Res)
  }
};
```

means:

```
final def method(var this: ThisType, var a: A, var b: B, ...): Res = {
  // _method(_$this: Test, a: A, b: B, ...){
  :start

  // body

  //   _method(nextThis, nextA, nextB, ...)
  this = nextThis
  a = nextA
  b = nextB
  ...
  goto :start
};
```

And this is exactly what you'll get after `scalac -Xprint:all` on your `loop` method, but `body` will be huge. So in your case:

```
...
case Some(x) =>
  this = this
  s = s.tail
  acc = accumulate(x, acc)
  goto :start
...
```

After `s = s.tail` you have no reference to the head of the stream.

Comment: This looks good.  In my case the method was not `final` but inside another method which works as well.  Thanks for the research!  Maybe I should have asked "how does tail call optimization work".  I knew about not keeping a reference in the calling code, but now I'm confident that passing it as an argument doesn't pose a problem.

Comment: @herman: `private` method is also not overridable, just like `final`. Note also that all methods of `object` are `final`.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases where this question comes up, the more important question is "does the calling code hang onto the head of stream?"

What really matters is that you passed the output from another method directly to `loop`, rather than assigning it to a `val` first.

That said, I would just avoid all possible confusion by using a simpler approach:

```
list.sliding(n).foldLeft(initialY)(accumulate)
```

Comment: The `Stream` is not infinite.  But it's big enough that I don't want to cache the values.  I've updated the question with code similar to the actual calling code.  Basically sliding over a million elements using a window size `n` that could potentially be several hundreds of elements.  So I wouldn't like to cache `n * 1000000` elements.

Comment: @Senia - well I never... I guess this is why I just use Iterators.

Comment: @senia hmm, I guess you're right: `@tailrec` confused me, it appears to be valid on calls that are not really recursive and I guess that is what helps with the stack overflow.  I'm still puzzled about how the `Stream` object on which `foldLeft` is initially called can already be garbage collected even while foldLeft` is still executing.

Comment: @herman At a guess, it's because tail recursive functions hang on to their arguments, but you don't need to pass the stream in as an argument when the method you're calling is a *member* of the `Stream` class

Comment: @herman: I was wrong! `Stream#foldLeft` is actually an optimized tail recursion! And `loop` method from question works on infinite `Stream` without stack overflow.

Comment: @senia - Bah! Don't scare me like that.

Comment: @senia LOL, how can I be expected to understand this stuff if even the experts get it wrong :)  Since you did the actual checking work, if you post this as an answer (maybe with code to prove it's working - although not necessary) I'll accept it.

Comment: @herman There's no such thing as an expert, just people who've learned enough to truly appreciate how much more there is that they could possibly learn.

Comment: @herman: "experts"? I guess I confused @KevinWright. And I'm a `C#` developer =).

Comment: *sigh* Then I'm leaving the answer as it now stands, and I'll be done with it.

Comment: @herman: I'll try to figure out how this optimization actually works.

Comment: @senia Thanks.  At least Kevin believed you for a moment :)

Comment: Ahh well... I tend to avoid streams, *precisely* because they result in this kind of confusion.

Comment: Good answer, Kevin!  A nit, though -- the function would have to be something like `( (soFar,x) => accumulate(x,soFar) )`, no?